# How to check if a user is authorized client side in passport.js?

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, ejs, web-deployment

In short I am attempting to have a modal prompt pop up if a user clicks a button that requires authorization to proceed. I am using passportjs strategy with sign in with google passport-google-oauth20. http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth20/

Either I need to trigger the modal server side through express, or prompt it on the client.js. On server.js I would need to figure out how to prompt for the modal, if im supposed to do this through the client js I need to figure out how to check if user is authorized.

**Clientside js attempt:**

**html button:**

`<a id="addBtn"><button class=" btn btn-success mr-2 frftr-grn" id="navbtn">Add</button></a>`

**client.js**

```
$(function () {
  $('#addBtn').click(function () {
      if (User.IsAuthenticated) {
        window.location.href = "/add";
      }
      else {
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
      }

  });
});
```

**Server side attempt:**

**html button:**

`<a id="addBtn" href="/add"><button class=" btn btn-success mr-2 frftr-grn" id="navbtn">Add</button></a>`

**server.js:**

```
app.get("/add", (req, res) => {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.render("add");
  }else{
    $('#myModal').modal("show");
  }  
});
```

Thank you for reading and any help is greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: In my opinion this should be handled by the client. You can store a session cookie when the user signs in, then check for the cookie on any authenticated action. See this link for how to do that with passport https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-introduction-to-oauth-using-passport-js-65ea5b621a/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understand that this is to be handled by cookies, but i am still not quite clear what I am supposed to do on the clientside as the article you showed me as the article's code only shows serverside commands. Is there something else i am missing?

Comment: You can implement a route on the server like /loggedInUser, that returns whether or not there is a logged in user, just like the middleware from the link. Then, inside your click function, where you check if the user is authenticated, you can make an ajax call to that route and only proceed implement your conditional logoc based on the response

Comment: well I already have all that stuff setup server side that authenticates and if it doesn't redirects to homepage. But you're saying to check if im authenticated i gotta ajax that? Admittedly that's not a forte of mine so that might mean i gotta study up. Alternatively what about checking my cookies? How would I go about querying to see if I have the authenticated cookie?